# Existence of a name which has elements with given truth values

Tags: set-theory, boolean-algebra, forcing

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a complete boolean algebra.

Let $ D $ be a set of $ \mathcal{A}-names $, and $ f:D \to \mathcal{A} $ any function (itself a name).

I wonder if it's possible to construct $ \sigma $ a $ \mathcal{A}-name $ satisfying:

$$
\forall x \in D \,\, [x \in \sigma] = f(x) 
$$

If not, maybe there are conditions over $f$ that makes it possible.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible in general.  A necessary and sufficient condition on $f$ is that for all $x,y\in D$, $f(x)\wedge [x=y]\leq f(y)$.  It is obvious that this is necessary, since for any $\sigma$ we must have $[x\in\sigma]\wedge[x=y]\leq [y\in \sigma]$.

For sufficiency, suppose $f$ satisfies this condition and simply let $\sigma=f$.  By definition, we have $$[y\in f]=\bigvee_{x\in D}([x=y]\wedge f(x)).$$  By hypothesis, if $y\in D$, then every term on the right is at most $f(y)$ so $[y\in f]\leq f(y)$.  On the other hand, by taking $x$ to be $y$, we see that one of the terms on the right is $f(y)$, so $[y\in f]\geq f(y)$.

Comment: I think I'm having a stupid moment - can you tell me where my (deleted) answer goes wrong?

Comment: @NoahSchweber: $\check{e}$ would make sense only when $e$ is an ordinary set, not a name.  Your argument would be correct if the set $D$ in the question consisted only of names of the form $\check{e}$.  But for arbitrary names, there might be different names in $D$ which become equal under $G$.

Comment: I don't think that's right? I mean the canonical name for $e$-viewed-as-a-set. So $e\not=d$ means $\check{e}[G]\not=\check{d}[G]$.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're doing.  In the question, the notation $[x\in\sigma]$ means the truth value of $x[G]$ being an element of $\sigma[G]$, _not_ the truth value of $x$ being an element of $\sigma[G]$.  So in the notation of your answer, you are interested in whether $e[G]\in \nu_g[G]$, not whether $e\in \nu_g[G]$.

Comment: Derp, thanks! Not my finest moment.